# UPDATE mysql rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I'm trying to update a lot (close to 500) of rows in mysql database. How can I make it with just 1 query?

```
UPDATE products SET product_qty=5 WHERE product_id=1,2,3,4,5...
```

...and it goes on and on until 500.

Comment: @Siyual my mistake, deleted comment. I misunderstood the question.

Comment: FYI... A *couple* is only ever two values.  500 can be either *several* or *many* depending on your interpretation.  But a *couple* is always only two.

Comment: @Siyual [couple](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/couple): 4. *an indefinite small number*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`BETWEEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operator:

```
UPDATE products SET product_qty=5 WHERE product_id BETWEEN 1 AND 500
```

If not all products with an ID in that range should be updated, you'll have to use the `IN` operator and construct the query with some PHP code:

```
UPDATE products SET product_qty=5 WHERE product_id IN (1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 11, ..., 346)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `product_id` values are consecutive, your can use a range operator, like `BETWEEN` or `<=`

```
UPDATE products SET product_qty=5 WHERE product_id BETWEEN 1 AND 500
```

or

```
UPDATE products SET product_qty=5 WHERE product_id <= 500
```